# What's the best way to determine if a temporary table exists in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

When writing a T-SQL script that I plan on re-running, often times I use temporary tables to store temporary data.  Since the temp table is created on the fly, I'd like to be able to drop that table only if it exists (before I create it).

I'll post the method that I use, but I'd like to see if there is a better way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
IF Object_Id('TempDB..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
END
```

Answer (score 16):

The OBJECT_ID function returns the internal object id for the given object name and type.  'tempdb..#t1' refers to the table #t1 in the tempdb database. 'U' is for user-defined table.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #t1

CREATE TABLE #t1
(
  id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  msg VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable
```

Comment: For SQL Server 2016 onwards.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'U' AND name = 'TempTable'
```

Comment: Keith, it looks like that query will find normal user tables, but not temporary tables.