# Drop a temporary table if it exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two lines of code in SQL that create two tables on the fly, i need to do something like

```
IF TABLE EXISTS 
    DROP IT AND CREATE IT AGAIN
ELSE
    CREATE IT
```

my lines are the following ones

```
CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)     
CREATE TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)
```

how can I apply that concept for these two tables in my procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to determine if a temporary table exists in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-temporary-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if temp table exist and delete if it exists before creating a temp table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659051/check-if-temp-table-exist-and-delete-if-it-exists-before-creating-a-temp-table)

Answer (score 236, accepted):

From SQL Server 2016 you can just use

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD
```

On previous versions you can use

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##CLIENTS_KEYWORD', 'U') IS NOT NULL
/*Then it exists*/
DROP TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD
CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD
(
   client_id INT
)
```

You could also consider truncating the table instead rather than dropping and recreating.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##CLIENTS_KEYWORD', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  TRUNCATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD
  (
     client_id INT
  )
```

Comment: can you also post the truncation below this approach , it might help me for the better :) thank you

Comment: hmm for some reason when I execute it it says that ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD is an invalid object name

Comment: @user - What version of SQL Server are you on? I'm on SQL Server 2008 and (think I) tested both for the case that the table did and did not exist. It might need wrapping the create in an `EXEC` so the parser doesn't complain on previous versions. i.e. use `EXEC('CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id INT)')`

Comment: ＋１ for `OBJECT_ID IS NULL` instead of `tempdb.sys.tables` query.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using the second one over the first one

Comment: It might be worth pointing out costs/benefits of `TRUNCATE` - e.g. regarding triggers, foreign keys, autoincrement values, dependent views etc.

Comment: @TobySpeight - the question is about temporary tables. Most of these points are of limited relevance to that.

Answer (score 17):

Check for the existence by retrieving its object_id:

```
if object_id('tempdb..##clients_keyword') is not null
    drop table ##clients_keyword
```

Answer (score 1):

What you asked for is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD

       CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)

    END
ELSE
   CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int) 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD

       CREATE TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)

    END
ELSE
   CREATE TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)
```

Since you're always going to create the table, regardless of whether the table is deleted or not; a slightly optimised solution is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD

CREATE TABLE ##CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int) 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD

CREATE TABLE ##TEMP_CLIENTS_KEYWORD(client_id int)
```